# ImageButton: Force square icon (height = WRAP_CONTENT, width = ?)

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

In my horizontal LinearLayout I have a TextEdit and an ImageButton. The ImageButton is as high as the TextEdit.

I'd like that the ImageButton is exactly as wide as it's long.

At the moment it looks like the width of the ImageButton is like when there is no scaling (ImageButton width [px] = unscaled drawable width [px]):

[image: example]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btSet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:src="@drawable/pin2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How it should look like:

[image: objective]

Comment: Just a little tip. When you set a layout_weight to a view, it's faster on the render to set width to 0dp.

Answer (score 23):

Try this, I think this should work:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btSet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pin2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btSet" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Explaination:** `centerInside` will assure that the image will scale proportionally within the bounds of the `ImageButton`. `adjustViewBounds="true"` will...well, adjust the view's bounds, if the image needed to be scaled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't work properly (Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/W8iFu.png). Do you know any other solution?

Comment: I edited my answer, try that out. Also, can you upload the button drawable you're using (if this doesn't work)?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. It doesn't seem to work yet (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Awbat.png). My drawable (_pin2_): http://i.imgur.com/eflnh.png

Comment: Getting a 502 (Bad Gateway) for the drawable link

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find an elegant solution. I did, however, find a solution. I've edited my answer with the solution. Sorry it's not as pretty as you might were hoping.

Comment: If you want, I do know of a way to programmatically solve this, but it will involve the screen having to redraw itself once, so for a split second you would see the sizes not correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It would be great if you could show me that.

Answer (score 6):

try adding

> adjustViewBounds="true"

to the ImageButton, that should clip the excess width

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btSet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pin" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't work properly (Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/W8iFu.png). Do you know any other solution?

Comment: Try removing tag scaleType and set layout_width and height to wrap_content

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/2456h.png Are you sure it works?

Comment: @SecStone If you physically scale your png to needed sizes it will fit accurate.

Comment: setting adjustViewBounds="true" worked for my case, I guess the image itself needs to be square for it to work

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

or `android:scaleType="centerInside"`

in the ImageButton in xml File.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Which values should I use for `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`?

Comment: you can use fill parent or wrap content as per your requirement...!!!
And please check the answer if you satisfied...!!!

Answer (score 2):

I might be a bit late to the party.
However there's an easy way to achieve this behavior by overriding the onMeasure().
Here's how it'd look like :

```
public class MySquareImageButton extends ImageButton {
    public MySquareImageButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MySquareImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MySquareImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //(1)if you want the height to match the width
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        //(2)if you want the width to match the height
        //super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

And then you'd simply replace your XML's ImageButton with this custom one :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.whatever_your_package.MySquareImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btSet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:src="@drawable/pin2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You'd simply put wrap_content to width or height, depending on which one you want to dictate the size of your button.
In the case you want your button to wrap its height to the image, and that the width simply matches the height, you'd use

```
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and use

```
        //(2)if you want the width to match the height
        //super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I was trying to create something that looked like this:
[image]

But what I was getting was this:
[image]

The `ImageButton` was getting stretched horizontally.
All the top answers didn't work for me. But I noticed people mentioning `layout_weight` and just looked it up out of curiosity and found the following on [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight):

> **Layout Weight**
>
> LinearLayout also supports assigning a weight to individual children with the android:layout_weight attribute. This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight. Default weight is zero.
>
> For example, if there are three text fields and two of them declare a weight of 1, while the other is given no weight, the third text field without weight will not grow and will only occupy the area required by its content. The other two will expand equally to fill the space remaining after all three fields are measured. If the third field is then given a weight of 2 (instead of 0), then it is now declared more important than both the others, so it gets half the total remaining space, while the first two share the rest equally

So basically, if you set the `layout_width` to be 0 for an element, it'll appear according to the dimensions of its content.
If you set it to anything else, the element will fight for extra space in the parent element that contains it; with more weighted elements taking up more space.

So, when I set `layout_width = 0` for both `TextView` and `ImageButton` in my example, neither of them takes up any extra space and they both huddle up to the left.

[image]

But when I set it to 1 for `TextView` and 0 for `ImageButton`, the `ImageButton` doesn't take any more space than required by its content; while the `TextView` takes up all the extra space and pushes `ImageButton` to the right.
Just the way I want it.
[image]

Initially, what had happened was both the elements were set to have a default `layout_weight` of 1 and hence both were equally competing for the extra space.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the weightSum to devide the size of controls accordingly...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:weightSum="1.0" >

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/txtName"
       android:layout_weight="0.8"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="0dp" 
       android:inputType="text"
       android:singleLine="true"/>

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/btSet"
       android:layout_weight="0.2"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:scaleType="fitEnd"
       android:src="@drawable/pin2" />

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If the app runs on small screen, I maybe need 25% or 30% of the space to display the button as a square. Is there also a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

as you want your `ImageButton` is stretchable &  exactly as wide as it's long, its better to use [`NinePatch Image`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch). you may find help form here [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) & [How does Android’s nine-patch tool work ?](http://jaanus.com/post/7878186745/how-does-androids-nine-patch-tool-work-from-a)

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:weightSum="1.0" >

<EditText
   android:id="@+id/txtName"
   android:layout_weight="0.75" // this work like percentage adjust as u want 70 or 75
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="0dp" 
   android:inputType="text"
   android:singleLine="true"/>

<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/btSet"
   android:layout_weight="0.25" // this work like percentage adjust as u want 25 or 30
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:scaleType="fitEnd"
   android:src="@drawable/pin2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to your ImageButton and the extra background will fade away:

```
android:layout_gravity="center|clip_horizontal"
```

hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into something like this and the other suggestions didn't help. What did help was setting the padding in the ImageButton:

```
android:padding="5dp"
```

Besides that, I didn't touch the original layout. The button became square on the 3 emulators that I tested (3.2, 4.4.2, 5.1)

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself,it works

Simply do the Following...

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Use Layout Weight ratio 5:1 inside a `LinearLayout` for `EditText` and `ImageButton`

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score -3):

You Can resize the Image button using px... like below...

```
    `android:layout_width="5px"
    android:layout_height="5px"`
```

Comment: im pretty sure he wants it to be scalable

Comment: Exactly ;) (However, it's not stated in the problem statement.)