# Force Android Button to Stay Square

Tags: android, image, button

I am reopening a question that was asked two years (and yes, I tried all the answers but there was no joy). The question asked two years ago: [ImageButton: Force square icon (height = WRAP_CONTENT, width = ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852568/imagebutton-force-square-icon-height-wrap-content-width)

I am faced with the same situation where I am attempting to align a Button (with a background image) with an EditText. The following is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Desired outcome]

The RelativeLayout I am using is:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_entry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/search_layout_height"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/search_layout_left"
    android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"    
    android:background="@drawable/search_box"
    android:inputType="text|number"
    android:textSize="@dimen/small_textsize"
    android:hint="@string/search_for_hint" 
    android:textColorHint="@color/mdgray"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/search_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/search_entry"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/search_entry"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_entry"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:background="@drawable/search_btn" />
```

However, what I am ending up with is:

[image: Current Outcome]

As you can see, it wants to stretch laterally.

Thoughts on how to make sure the button stays square?

Comment: Have you tried using an ImageView instead, and use android:src="..." instead of android:background? You may also need to add android:clickable="true"

Comment: Yes, I did but the result was not to my liking.  I could not force the image to the edge of the button which made a gap between the EditText box and the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using Wrap_content you need to instead use an actual value if you want to keep an aspect ratio 1:1. If you want it to scale properly for all devices I would say in java code define the screen size and use the to calculate the width and height of the image for example:

```
button.setWidth(screenWidth/6);
button.setHeight(screenWidth/6);
```

Comment: That is what I did.  I added the following to my Activity:                                                       activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
      int searchEntryHeight = searchEntry.getHeight();
      searchButton.setHeight(searchEntryHeight);
         searchButton.setWidth(searchEntryHeight);
     } 
 });

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ImageButton and make a class that extends ImageButton that will override the `onMeasure` method of it where in there you can make the background as a square using its background image's minimum size as the width and hieght to form a perfect square that will never deform the image.

**example:**

```
public class ImageViewPefectSquare extends ImageButton{

public ImageViewPefectSquare(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ImageViewPefectSquare(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ImageViewPefectSquare(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int measuredWidth = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),
            widthMeasureSpec);
    int measuredHeight = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(),
            heightMeasureSpec);
    // Ensure this view is always square.
    int min = Math.min(measuredHeight, measuredWidth);
    setMeasuredDimension(min, min);
}
}
```

what it is doing is that it will calculate for the minimum size of the image and use it as the width and height to make it a perfect square.

**Use it as xml:**

```
<com.youpackage.ImageViewPefectSquare
android:id="@+id/search_btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/search_entry"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/search_entry"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_entry"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:background="@drawable/search_btn" />
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work and the reason is, I have to take into account the height of the adjoining EditText which is not available to me with the ImageViewPefectSquare button object.